# A page is throwing an error when I try to access it through an iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I'm trying to show a part of a page through an iframe. It is a [solar log](https://www.solar-log.com/en/products-components/monitoring-solar-logTM/solar-log-1200/) page hosted on the integrated web server connecting to a private network. If I access the page through the browser it shows all the data, but when I try to access it with the iframe it gives back the solar log page but shows a solar log error. So the connection is good I just don't know why it changes from browser to iframe.

Here is the iframe I'm trying to use to access the site.

```
<div id="solar-log">
<iframe id="solarlogif" src="http://<the location of the web server>" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts"></iframe>
</div>
```

The 404 error I'm getting in the console is `http://<the location of the web server>/emulate/`

I'd like for the page to show in the same way it is shown when accessed through the browser. I'm using Firefox 41.0.1.

Comment: As error says, Your page requires some user information to authenticate the request. When you directly load page in browser user information through cookie, sessions, header is being passed, perhaps. Try to pass authentication token with iframe src. Search Google, you would find examples.

Comment: There is no authentication. I've tried going incognito and using a different browser that never accessed the original page.